# How to get bugreport data that Battery Historian calculates in csv

Tags: android, export-to-csv, bug-reporting

I need to extract data from bugreport.zip file that can be generated from android using adb. Battery Historian shows different parameters graphically. But we need to collect that different data in csv format. Is there any way or software that does this? Where can I find what the parameters and events listed in Battery Historian actually means?

Answer (score 1):

Battery Historian has a function named **processFile** which generates a csv output file by parsing bugreport data.

In the github source code of the project, /cmd/history-parse/local_history_parse.go contains the function.

https://github.com/google/battery-historian/blob/master/cmd/history-parse/local_history_parse.go

You can get two types of summary output from this function as written in the code,

*"1. batteryLevel 2. totalTime"*

This project is majorly written in *go*. So, first you need to have *go* installed and the *battery historian github* project in your local machine. If you already don't have it, you may follow the steps described here,

http://en.miui.com/thread-349584-1-1.html

Now, from command line you need to run a similar command like this to access the function mentioned above to get a csv file containing parsed data.

```
    go run cmd\history-parse\local_history_parse.go --summary=batteryLevel --csv="D:\battery_res.csv" --input=C:\adb\bugreport-N2G47H-2018-04-22-23-44-44.zip
```

--summary="" can be either *"batteryLevel"* or *"totalTime"*

--csv=""  give here the output csv file path.

--input="" give here the input bugreport file path which is your *bugreport.zip* file path

Comment: The generated csv files are not quite the files we need. They are too general.

Comment: Any chance we found a way?